# C# library for audio resampling that has the same abilities as FFmpeg

Tags: c#, c++, c, ffmpeg, naudio

I have to use a pure C# solution for resampling audio, which can produce me the exact same results as FFmpeg's audio sampling can.

**FFmpeg** first builds some kind of polyphase filter bank, and then uses that for the sampling process (sorry for the vague phrasing, but I'm not too familiar with this topic). According to this brief [documentation](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/resample2_8c.html#68169c9ed4e66f474a7d90cd224bf567), the initialization can be customized this way:

```c
AVResampleContext* av_resample_init(
    int     out_rate,
    int     in_rate,
    int     filter_length,
    int     log2_phase_count,
    int     linear,
    double  cutoff   
    )
```

The parameters are:

- **out_rate**: output sample rate
- **in_rate**: input sample rate
- **filter_length**: length of each FIR filter in the filterbank relative to the cutoff freq
- **log2_phase_count**: log2 of the number of entries in the polyphase filterbank
- **linear**: if 1 then the used FIR filter will be linearly interpolated between the 2 closest, if 0 the closest will be used
- **cutoff**: cutoff frequency, 1.0 corresponds to half the output sampling rate

I'd need to use a C# library that is configurable in the same depth. I've been trying to use **NAudio** (more specifically, its `WaveFormatConversionStream` class), but there, I could only set the input and output sample rates, so I didn't get the expected results.

So, is there a C# lib that could resample with the same settings as FFmpeg can? Or one that has almost all of these settings or similar ones? Note: I need a C# solution, not a wrapper!

Comment: libsoxr is made in C, but it is a self-contained resampler that should be easier to port than looking at the entirety of ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I'll need to write it from scratch eventually, I'll check out this option, too.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `WaveFormatConversionStream` (which uses ACM codecs), NAudio includes another resampler that can be accessed as a DirectX Media Object (DMO), or (in the latest prerelease of NAudio 1.7) as a Media Foundation Transform. These can be used in Windows Vista and above. Sadly I think they are not available in XP (but has been a while since I tried).

The DMO version found is in the `Resampler` class (there is also a `ResamplerDmoStream`), and the Media Foundation Version is in `MediaFoundationResampler`. They actually both create the same underlying object, but on the MFT version I have added a property called `ResamplerQuality` which allows you to choose anywhere between 1 (linear interpolation) and 60 (max quality). In [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET) I include a spectogram of a resampled sine wave sweep and you will see that the quality is very good.

You could easily make the same change to the `Resampler` class if you want to go the DMO route, since it has access to [IWMResamplerProps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff819251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which allows you to set the half filter length (which is the same value between 1 and 60).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I was trying to sort out another problem of the same project in the meanwhile, and I didn't want to mix the 2 things. So, I tried the MFT version, and the results I got were pretty close to the original ones, but I think I'll still need to port the original FFmpeg code anyway. I even iterated through all the possible values for the ResamplerQuality to see how much of the result will be the same as the expected, as I was hoping for a miracle :P